# How do you show the last modified date for an uploaded file in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

In mediawiki, I can show a link to a file using:

```
[[Media:File.pdf|A file]]
```

Results in

[A file](http://File.pdf)

But how can I get the the last modified date for an uploaded file? I would like to show the timestamp alongside that link, rather than having to go to the file page for it. Is there a way to do this?

[A file](http://File.pdf) [Timestamp]

Does this require an extension of some sort? I am unable to find any documentation on getting metadata for uploaded files.

Answer (score 2):

It would require custom logic, yes (which is normally packaged into extensions but in simple cases you can just add it directly to your config file). You can use the [HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd) hook for example:

```
global $wgHooks;
$wgHooks['HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd'][] = function(
    LinkRenderer $linkRenderer, LinkTarget $target,
    $isKnown, &$text, &$attribs, &$ret
) {
    if ( $linkTarget->inNamespace( NS_FILE ) ) {
        $file = wfFindFile( $linkTarget->getText() );
        if ( $file && $file->exists() && $file->isLocal() ) {
            $text .= ' ' . $file->getTimestamp();
        }
    }
};
```

(untested) which will put the timestamp inside the link but it's close enough.